# Network policy to prevent cross namespace communication

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy

How to define a network policy to prevent communication across pods in different namespaces within the same K8s cluster?

Comment: https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/04-deny-traffic-from-other-namespaces.md

Comment: The Link is actually the right answer. Why do you add it as a link inside the comment?

Answer (score 5):

Checkout the git repo at [here](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/04-deny-traffic-from-other-namespaces.md) for many netpolicy usecases, following is one of it.

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: deny-from-other-namespaces
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}
```

> ***Note a few things about this manifest:**

> namespace: default deploys it to the default namespace.     it applies the policy to ALL pods in
> default namespace as the spec.podSelector.matchLabels is empty and
> therefore selects all pods.     it allows traffic from ALL pods in the
> default namespace, as spec.ingress.from.podSelector is empty and
> therefore selects all pods.*